# class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found at remoteMessage.getNotification()

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My current emulator play service dependency version is 12.0.1.I added all my firebase dependency with 12.0.1.And it's work fine.But when i call remoteMessage.getNotification() then thrown an exception

```
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found at  remoteMessage.getNotification()
```

Here is my all firebase dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

Here is FirebaseMessaging Service Class code

```
public class FirebaseMessageing extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("New  Request")){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

}
```

i also defined my class into the manifest file

```
 <service android:name=".Service.FirebaseMessageing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Service.FirebaseService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: AFAIK, having really old dependencies would cause such errors. Try using the latest ones and see if it changes things. Or is it not possible because of the play services dependency?

Comment: i have found  my solution.I added firebase database ui 3.2.2 ..Thanks for help.

Comment: But how can i upgrade play service version ?